# shinyApp command in shiny package?

Tags: r, shiny

I have installed shiny in RStudio running R 2.15.3.
I load the package by `library(shiny)`
But when I try to use shinyApp command I'll get the following

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage()
server <- function(input,output){}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)

Error: could not find function "shinyApp"
```

And even when I'm trying to use R help by :

```
?shinyApp
```

the answer is :

```
No documentation for ‘shinyApp’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??shinyApp’
```

And it is very disappointing because this command is one of the essential commands that you need all time !

I have to mention that the sample code I have tried to compile, is from official tutorial by shiny (shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial) ! So basically it should work.

Can somebody help me on this please !

Comment: Just a guess, but you might want to install the latest R version? See https://www.r-project.org/

Comment: According to the documentation, [https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shiny/shiny.pdf], `These functions create Shiny app objects from either an explicit UI/server pair (
shinyApp
), or by
passing the path of a directory that contains a Shiny app (
shinyAppDir
).  You generally shouldn’t
need to use these functions to create/run applications;  they are intended for interoperability pur-
poses, such as embedding Shiny apps inside a
knitr
document`

Comment: You cannot see documentation because you write app with upper letter.
Use ?shinyApp instead ?shinyAPP

Comment: What version of shiny are you using? Check with `sessionInfo()`. In older versions it used to be called `runApp()` I think. You are using a fairly old version of R so you might not be able to install the latest version of the package.

Comment: I have updated R to 3.4.0 , but still I have the same issue, and it is appearing on windows. when I'm using mac to compile it, It is working without a problem !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update R to the version required by Shiny (>=3.0.0) then run `update.packages()` in R.

The reason you're getting this error is probably because you installed Shiny under an old R version, and thus, you got an old version of Shiny. When you updated R on your Windows computer, it used the packages already there in your old R installation, i.e., the old version of Shiny.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, the issue comes from not having the proper configuration of R and shiny, however in RStudio (which I'd asume you are using since you are following the tutorial) a much easier solution is to click on the "Run App" button and it should give you the option to install shiny if it detects its missing